# "Restore justice"

Tags: word-usage, collocations

Do you use "restore justice"?

For example, "Dissection is performed to determine the cause of death as well as to restore justice and is therefore for the benefit of the deceased."

Comment: Are you referring to [autopsies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autopsy)? (We do not refer to standard post-mortem examinations of humans as dissections.) Either way, I don't think this is a natural setting for the phrase "restore justice." Maybe you can elaborate a bit on what you're trying to say?

Comment: When you talk about people you don't use the word"dissection". I didn't know that. But when you talk about animals do you native speakers use it? I mean when investigating a suspicious death which can be a murder and which can lead to catching the murderer in this case it will benefit the the deceased person and restore justice so that the murderer will be punished.

Comment: You just used "restore justice" a second time without explaining what you intend it to mean. If a person is dead, he can't "benefit" from an autopsy /  post-mortem - and assuming he can't be brought back to life, I don't think "restore" is a suitable verb here.

Comment: Under "restore justice" I mean this "I  mean when investigating a suspicious death which can be a murder and which can lead to catching the murderer in this case it will benefit the the deceased person and restore justice so that the murderer will be punished." So by restoring justice I mean arresting the murderer. Maybe "benefit the investigation"?

Comment: The usual phrase is "do justice", not "restore justice". As FFRM said, a dead person can't be said to benefit. Any benefit that accrues from doing justice for a murder accrues to their relatives and society in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to express what I think you are trying to express.

There is a phrase "restorative justice" which means "punishments that make criminals repair the damage that has been done"  For example, a robber might have to meet and listen to and apologise to the people he/she has robbed.  Your example is not about "restorative justice"

I think you could say "seek justice for the deceaced". I'm not sure you can say "for the benefit of the deceased" as a dead person can't be benefitted (or harmed). So the benefit in catching the killer is for their relatives and society in general.